backup to router and scp to local pc
I want to make my openwrt backup with command from my local terminal, pretty easy, but my problem is after that, it is when I try to bring back the backup to my local pc. Here what I have for now, first part is ok:
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@192.168.1.1 sysupgrade --create-backup /tmp/main_backup.tar.gz 

with that command I create my router's backup and I want to scp that backup to my local pc.

it's not clear what the problem is that you're encountering, and what specifically you're backing up. "OpenWRT" is a family of operating systems, not a specific set of data.

Other than that, "pretty simple" might not quite be true from your perspective; you're doing things that are so wrong that I have to admit I don't even know what the intent behind doing them are. What is the reason you're trying to execute /tmp/main_backup.tar.gz ? It's a compressed archive, not an executable.

I edited my question, but I don't want to execute the file, I just want to scp that file to my pc

you still haven't described the problem. Generally, scp is easy to use scp source target, and that applies here as well. You will have to show us what you do execute and how it fails for us to be able to help you. You have to assume that we're not sitting next to you, seeing what you're doing!

Base on information in question, script with scp:
#!/bin/bash

# Create tgz
ssh root@192.168.1.1 sysupgrade --create-backup /tmp/main_backup.tar.gz 

# Copy to local dir
scp root@192.168.1.1:/tmp/main_backup.tar.gz <local dir>

